# VTK CMakeLists.txt for test classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vtk

A typical '**CMakeLists.txt**' included with a VTK wiki example is shown below;

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(Arrow)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(Arrow MACOSX_BUNDLE Arrow)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(Arrow ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  target_link_libraries(Arrow vtkHybrid)
endif()
```

I'm able to build the examples successfully in Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012.

[image: Arrow example]

I would like to write a '**CMakeLists.txt**' file so that I can build/run a **test class** (i.e. This one [ReebGraph/Testing](http://vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=tree;f=Filters/ReebGraph/Testing/Cxx;h=52aa70ab8410c8c51afa16f48092c2f65bda8b93;hb=HEAD)). I'm assuming I'm right in saying that they require different kinds of make files. The '**CMakeLists.txt**' for '**TestReebGraph.cxx**' is shown below.

```
vtk_add_test_cxx(TestReebGraph.cxx NO_DATA NO_VALID NO_OUTPUT)
vtk_test_cxx_executable(${vtk-module}CxxTests)
```

How would I write one for the testing class? Do I somehow have to merge the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cmake commands vtk_* are for writing tests inside of the VTK CMake system. What you'll want is to first enable_testing() in your CMakeLists.txt. Then you'll have to change the function TestReebGraph to be called 'main' in TestReebGraph.cxx. You can then use add_test(TestReebGraph TestReebGraph.cxx) to build the test that you have presumably copied into your project directory.

Comment: Yeah managed to figure this out, thanks for your answer though.